# How to show table values in a blade view, which returned from laravel controller using json_encode()?

Tags: javascript, php

Unable to display table values in blade view

I have a laravel controller which is returning a data set through json_encode(). I do not know which code i have to use to display the data set in my blade view.

Controller.php

```
    <?php

     namespace App\Http\Controllers;

     use Illuminate\Http\Request;
     use DB;

     class local extends Controller
     {
         function index()
    {
$data = DB::table('data')
       ->select(
        DB::raw('alliance as alliance', 'rank as rank'),
        DB::raw('count(*) as number'))
       ->where('rank','=', 1)
       ->groupBy('alliance')
       ->get();
      $data2 = DB::table('data')
       ->select(
        DB::raw('partyname as partyname', 'rank as rank'),
        DB::raw('count(*) as number'))
       ->where('rank','=', 1)
       ->groupBy('partyname')
       ->get();

      $data3 = DB::table('data')
       ->select(
        DB::raw('statename as statename', 'pcname as pcname','partyname as partyname', 'total as total','rank as rank'),
        DB::raw('count(*) as number'))
       ->where('rank','=', 1)
       ->groupBy('statename')
       ->get();

     $array3[] = ['Statename', 'Number'];

      foreach($data3 as $key => $value)
      {

       $array3[++$key] = [$value->statename, $value->number];

      }
      return view('lok_piechart_2014')->with('alliance',json_encode($array))->with('partyname',json_encode($array2))->with('statename',json_encode($array3));

     }

}
```

Blade Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Results</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <style type="text/css">
   .box{
    width:800px;
    margin:0 auto;
   }
  </style>
  @include('includes.head')
  <script type="text/javascript">
   var analytics = <?php echo $alliance; ?>;
   var analytics2 = <?php echo $partyname; ?>;
   google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
   google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
   function drawChart()
   {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(analytics);
    var options = {
     title : 'Percentage TN, AP & others',
     chartArea:{right:0,top:50,width:"100%",height:"100%"},
     is3D: true
     };
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);

    var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(analytics2);
    var options2 = {
     title : 'Percentage by Partywise',
     chartArea:{left:0,top:50,width:"100%",height:"100%"},
     is3D: true,
     legend:{alignment: "stat", position:"right"}
    };
    var chart2 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));
    chart2.draw(data2, options2);
    }
</script>

 </head>
 <body>
  @include('includes.topnav')
  @include('includes.bottomnav')
  <div class="container">
    <h3 align="left">Results</h3><br />
    <div class="panel panel-default" style="width:1000px; height:1000px;">
      <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Pie Chart</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body" align="left">
         <div id="chart_div" style="width:800px; height:400px;"> </div>
         <div id="chart_div2" style="width:800px; height:400px;"> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The first two data set is for Pie Chart and the 3rd data set is for table.

I would like to display the 3rd data set as a table in blade view.

Comment: put your `blade` here for better understanding

Comment: why do you use json_encode (you can remove it and simplify code) ?

Comment: Gulshan: I have updated my complete code for controller & added blade view. Please check & help me
If i have to change the return view type, please guide me.

Comment: Kamil, I am trying to push 3 different data sets from the controller. The first two data set is for Pie chart and 3rd data set is for table.